# Get key follow value in array

Tags: arrays

i have array in PHP that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [router.class] => Home
    [router.method] => Array
        (
            [gioi-thieu] => about
        )

    [router.params] => Array
        (
            [gioi-thieu] => name,age,job
        )

)
```

I would like to get the value of `router.params['gioi-thieu']`, where `gioi-thieu` is the key of value about `([router.method]['gioi-thieu'] = about)`.
somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP array is $arr you can access it by calling $arr['router.params']['gioi-thieu'].
Below is a working example:

```
 <?php
        $arr = array(
        "router.class" => "Home",
        "router.method" => array("gioi-thieu" => "about"),
        "router.params" => array("gioi-thieu" => "name,age,job")
        );
        echo $arr['router.params']['gioi-thieu'];
    ?>
```

Hope this helps!